# How to Create a online based HTML Source code editor like the one in W3Schools.com using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create `HTML` Source code editor like W3Schools

I have tried following using **jQuery syntax Highlight** Its Works as follow

[image: Tried Example]

It works perfect, but when I try to edit it then it is not responding to large code all time.
My HTML code is more that 12000 to 15000 lines, so its not useful.

I want to create as follow like W3Schools

[image: What I want]

How can I create like above?

Please give me any idea.

Suggest any Plugin to create it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I got The Answare**

now its responce is great I tried more than 100000 Line of html in it & its working great

I changed the plugin from **JQuery syntax Highlight** to **jquery-codemirror**

follow The Following steps to setup the code mirror

step 1: Download the CodeMirror from [Jquery-CodeMirror-Plugin](https://codemirror.net/)

step 2: Unzip the plugin file & add that unziped folder in your solution

step 3: Add the reference of following

1. `plugin/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css`
2. `plugin/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js`

step 4: add `<textarea>` in Your `html` with the class `codemirror-textarea` as follow

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CodeMirror</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="plugin/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea class="codemirror-textarea"></textarea>

        <!-- javascript -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/default.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

step 5: Add the following code in your JS

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //code here...
    var code = $(".codemirror-textarea")[0];
    var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(code, {
        lineNumbers : true
    });
});
```